# After Deleting File Successfully in kotlin when i try to pick new image again deleted image showing in gallery

Tags: file, kotlin, copy

```
 //copying file from one place to other
private fun copyFile(oldFileLoc: String, fileName: String, catFolderName: String): String {

    val newdir: File = this.getDir(catFolderName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) //Don't do
    Log.d(TAG, newdir.toString())
    if (!newdir.exists()) {
        newdir.mkdirs()
        Log.d(TAG, "createFolder: Creating")
    }
    val to = File("$newdir/$fileName")
    val from = File(oldFileLoc)
    Log.d(TAG, "Old File Location $oldFileLoc")

    val inStream: InputStream = FileInputStream(from)
    val outStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(to)

    val lenghtOfFile: Int = inStream.available()
    val buf = ByteArray(1024)
    var len: Int
    var total: Long = 0
    var fileTotalSize = getFileSize(from)
    while (inStream.read(buf).also { len = it } != -1) {
        total += len.toLong()
        var bytes: Int = (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile).toInt()
        outStream.write(buf, 0, len)
        var res = FileSize.bytesToHuman(total.toLong())
        updateNotification(bytes, res + " / " + fileTotalSize.toString())
        if (isInterrupted!!) {
            break
        }
        outStream.flush()
    }
    if (!isInterrupted!!) {
        Log.d(TAG, "copyFile: Not Interupted")
        from.delete()
    }
    inStream.close()
    outStream.flush()
    outStream.close()
    return to.toString()
}
```

This is my method For Copying file from one place to Another.Copying file is Good after copying I deleting old file it was also good but when I try to pick new file it showing me already deleted file if I selected that file app was crashing even though for moving file also same After moving file successfully when I picking new file to move old file still showing in picker if I again select that app was crashing again please help me it takes already two days for me this Bug

What I Want Is?
I am developing vault app so that I am picking files and moving/copying files to my secure appfolder after successfully moving when I try to move new file so iopend picker again there I see last time I moved file but when I clicked that app crashes

My doubt was ?
i already moved file and deleted file then wy still showing in files when I try to pick new image or file is that any cache why I got this doubt because when I go to real gallery and checked no files showing there

After moving file still showing like cache when i try to pick another file if I click that file app crashing because there is no file there

Comment: Can you explain why you’re copying by had rather than using library methods? e.g. `Files.copy`?

Comment: Note that `File.delete()` returns a `boolean` which you ignore. This `boolean` indicates success or failure…

Comment: this might actually be a bug in the gallery app. I remember experiencing something like that before. Deleting photos from outside the gallery app wouldn't prevent them from showing up in the gallery app because the gallery app merely shows thumbnails it generated before. I have no idea if this is something similar and no idea how to fix

Comment: I want to be file to move from one place to another and I want to delete old file even copying also I found same bug

Comment: I got Finally Answer that is very easy using content provider delete the file so no cache will be showing like that and bugs are fixed